# colocar en columnas segun un valor

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando mostrar una variable en pantalla que se debe visualizar en  un div diferente según cuál sea su valor. Es decir, tengo dos divs (simulando columnas) y por ejemplo tengo un array de valores 0 o 1. Según sea su valor debe salir en uno u otro div.
Tal como lo tengo hecho, me sale algo así[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto código

```css
.col1{
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 22%;
 background-color: red;
 height: 100px;
}
.col2{
 position: relative;
 left: 500px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 22%;
 background-color: yellow;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
$par =[ 0,1, 0 ,2,0,0];
  foreach ($par as $p) {

 if($p == 0){?>
  <div class="col1">
    <?php echo "El valor es: ".$p; ?>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>


  <?php if($p != 0){?>
  <div class="col2">
    <?php echo "El valor es: ".$p; ?>
  </div>
  <?php }

  
  }
```

Lo que yo quiero es que salga sin mostrar divs intermedios y sin dejar los espacios

Espero que se entienda lo que quiero. Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar grid css para simplificar un poco las cosas, ejemlo (comentarios en el código):

```
<?php
$par = [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0];
// creas variables para almacenar las celdas de cada columna
$column1 = '';
$column2 = '';
// haces el foreach y vas concatenando las celdas
foreach ($par as $p) {
  if($p == 0) {
    $column1 .= '<div class="col1">El valor es: ' . $p . '</div>';
  } else {    
    $column2 .= '<div class="col2">El valor es: ' . $p . '</div>';
  }
}
?>

<!-- Ya solo nos queda mostrarlo -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">
    <?= $column1 ?>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <?= $column2 ?>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- añadimos el css -->
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.column > div {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1px;
}
.col1 {
    background-color: red;
}
.col2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

Resultado:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.column > div {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1px;
}
.col1 {
    background-color: red;
}
.col2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="col1">El valor es: 0</div>
    <div class="col1">El valor es: 0</div>
    <div class="col1">El valor es: 0</div>
    <div class="col1">El valor es: 0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="col2">El valor es: 1</div>
    <div class="col2">El valor es: 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionó. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear el html para las dos columnas de esta manera:

```php
<?php
// example code
$par =[ 0,1, 0 ,2,0,0];

$col1 = "";
$col2 = "";
foreach ($par as $p) {

if($p == 0){
 $col1 .= 
  "<div class='col1'>
    El valor es: {$p}
  </div>";
}

if($p != 0){
  $col2 .= 
  "<div class='col2'>
    El valor es:{$p}
  </div>";
 }

}
```

Ahora puedes utilizar `$col1` y `$col2` allá donde los necesites:

```
echo $col1;
.......
echo $col2;
```

#### Actualización

El OP comenta:

> Gracias por tu respuesta. Así se han eliminado los elementos que salían vacíos pero no coloca las dos columnas en paralelo

A continuación puedes utilizar las dos variables de esta manera:

```
<section>
<article>
<?php echo $col1; ?>
</article>
<article>
<?php echo $col1; ?>
</article>  
</section>
```

Lo que resultaría en un HTML así:

```css
section{display:flex; width:100vw;}

[class ^=col]{
  width:45vw;
  margin:1em .5em;
  border:1px solid;
  line-height:100px;
 height: 100px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<section>
<article>
<div class='col1'>
    El valor es: 0
  </div>
<div class='col1'>
    El valor es: 0
  </div>
<div class='col1'>
    El valor es: 0
  </div>
<div class='col1'>
    El valor es: 0
  </div>
</article>
<article>
<div class='col2'>
    El valor es:1
  </div>
<div class='col2'>
    El valor es:2
</div>
</article>  
</section>
```

Para colocar las dos columnas en paralelo basta con añadir `section{display:flex;}` en el CSS. Alternativamente puedes utilizar `article{float:left}` o `article{display:inline-block}` u otro método que te guste para poner las dos columnas en paralelo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Así se han eliminado los elementos que salían vacíos pero no coloca las dos columnas en paralelo

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. He editado mi respuesta. Por favor echale una mirada

Comment: Muchas gracias. No lo he logrado del todo de esta forma pero es el camino